# Route traffic from OpenVPN to LAN on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, iptables, openvpn

I have a VPN server up and running using TUN and landing remote networks on the local machine in an, otherwise unused, subnet. The local machine has a LAN in a separate subnet.

The remote network is routing network traffic correctly, as routing rules are being correctly advertising routes, however, it looks like the CentOS OpenVPN server's iptables is blocking traffic from the VPN to the local network.

Here are the IPs involved:
Local server:
eth0: 10.9.1.10/29 (gw:10.9.1.1)
tun1194: 10.250.0.1/32 destination 10.250.0.2 (on local subnet 10.250.0.0/16)

Remote client:
ifconfig-push 10.250.0.5 10.250.0.6

Notes:
I can ping the remote gw (10.250.0.6) from the local network
I can ping the local gw (10.250.0.1) from any remote device
I CAN'T ping anything on 10.9.1.0/29 from the remote subnet (message from 10.250.0.1 = "host prohibited"), but I can from the local server.

I do have firewall rules that are already working to access, say, a single service on other networks connected to the server, like, for instance, this is working:
-A FORWARD -s 10.250.0.0/16 -d 10.0.1.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

But I can't get a rule going to allow all traffic from 10.250.0.0/16 to address items on the 10.9.1.1/29.

Shouldn't this allow it, or am I missing something in this rule?
-A FORWARD -s 10.250.0.0/16 -d 10.9.1.1/29 -j ACCEPT

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... This seems to work (but is too broad for me):
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.1.0/24 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
BUT, this doesn't...:
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.1.0/24 -d 10.9.1.1/29 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

Comment: Show the current `iptables` rules.